# onClick setState is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, modal-dialog, state

First of all, I've had a look at other answers and that didn't help.

I have a modal that is passed in a onClose function prop. When the cancel button is clicked it should trigger the onClose function which basically sets the showModal state to false. However, upon clicking the button I get an error that onClose is not a function.

I have checked the type of onClose prop and its coming back as an object. I don't know why.

This is how I am calling the Modal from the parent.

```
<Modal
   onClose={() => this.setState((prevState) => ({
      showModal: {
         ...prevState.showModal,
         confirmation: false,
        },
    }))}
```

/>

and this is what the modal looks like.

```
const Modal = (onClose) => {
  return (
    <div className="Background" >
      <div className="Container">
        <div className="Title">Title of the modal</div>
        <div className="Body">Body of the modal</div>
        <div className="Footer">
          <button type="button" onClick={() => onClose()}>Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

This is the error from console.

[image]

Comment: `const Modal = ({onClose}) => {`. You need to destruct the props in order to get `onClose`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this line

```
const Modal = (onClose) => {
```

to

```
const Modal = ({onClose}) => {
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//be sure this is being used in a class component! (not a functional) 
export YourClassComponent extends React.ClassComponent {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.onCloseModal = this.onCloseModal.bind(this);
    }

    onCloseModal = () => {
      this.setState((prevState) => ({ 
        showModal: {
          ...prevState.showModal,
          confirmation: false,
      }}))
    };

    render() {
      <Modal onClose={this.onCloseModal} />
    };
};
    // In you Modal.jsx, see the prop is setted directly no need to create a new ref to call it
const Modal = ({ onClose }) => {
  return (
    <div className="Background" >
      <div className="Container">
        <div className="Title">Title of the modal</div>
        <div className="Body">Body of the modal</div>
        <div className="Footer">
          <button type="button" onClick={onClose}>Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```